# How to start a bounty on the stackexchange Android app

Tags: feature-request, support, bounties, android-app

I can't see any button for starting a bounty on the mobile application of Stack Exchange.
Could someone please help me on where to find this feature ?

If it's impossible, could this feature be implemented?

Comment: Is it possible to implement this feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.

However you can do it in the browser.

1. Find a question and tap more.

[image]

Then open it in the browser.

[image]

Then, start a bounty in the browser. Note: When you login, complete the action with Chrome and **NOT** the Stack Exchange app.

[image]

Then add a bounty in the normal way.

Comment: so it's not possible to start a bounty direclty from the app, where can I suggest this feature to be added ?

Comment: I've already suggested an edit to put this as a feature request

Comment: Ok I've just seen it :) Thank you very much Mr George :)

Comment: @George this was already asked, closed as dupe. (nothing wrong in having both, just letting you know :))